# DRF overflowError: date value out of range trough serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Hello when a request is sent with data

```
[{"valid_from": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "valid_to": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"}]
```

How to limit the min year to 2020, I tried adding validators in the model but DRF executes first, so it is not working, how to stop it on DRF level.
If they pass the date.min in my serializer it raises `overflowError: date value out of range`

## My solution

```
class ValidateMinDateSerialier(serializers.Serializer):
    @staticmethod
    def is_date(value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d.+', value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        invalid_dates = []
        for key, value in data.items():
            if self.is_date(value):
                if not re.findall(r'2\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d.+', value):
                    invalid_dates.append(key)

        error_dict = {field: [_('Invalid date. The year must start with 2xxx')] for field in invalid_dates}

        if error_dict != {}:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error_dict, code=400)

        return super(ValidateMinDateSerialier, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

and then inherit `ValidateMinDateSerialier` in my serializer. But is this okay?

I have to put it on every serializer which accepts dates is there a global way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

On your serializer, you can validate individual fields

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
    ...

    def validate_valid_from(self, value):
        """
        Check that the blog post is about Django.
        """
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
        return value
```

Check docs for more [validation process.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)